# Select images from attribute value magento

Tags: magento

I have this piece of code:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
->addAttributeToSelect('*') 
->setPageSize(4) 
->setCurPage(4); 

foreach ($collection as $product) {
$image = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA).'catalog/product'.$product->getImage();

echo '<img src="'.$image.'" WIDTH=245 HEIGHT=245>';
}
```

This works perfect and show 4 product image's.
How can i get 4 product images from the attribute color when it is equal to white ?

When i try this i get a error:

```
->addAttributeToSelect('color', 'white')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
->addAttributeToSelect('*') 
->addAttributeToFilter('color', 'white')
->setPageSize(4) 
->setCurPage(4);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I receive this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR

Comment: Thank you so much! can you explain me what was wrong ?

Comment: http://edmondscommerce.github.io/magento/magento-addattributetofilter-and-addattributetoselect.html